# What is a faster method to calculate hourly totals from a pandas DataFrame than a for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame with about 200,000 rows of raw data.  Each row has start and stop times that can span an hour to years.  I am using a for loop to calculate a total for each hour of a year; each hourly total sums records that span that hour.  I am calculating hourly totals for a full year, or about 24 * 365 = 8760 hours.  Even running this for only 1,000 rows of raw data takes about 40 seconds on my laptop.  I'm looking for a much faster alternative.

I extracted the logic to create this standalone code, which runs successfully in Python 3.10.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import random


def make_test_data(records: int = 1000) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """

    :param records: int: the number of records to create for tthe est data set.
    :return: pd.DataFrame with columns ['INTERFACE', 'CLASS', 'START_TIME',
             'STOP_TIME', 'CAPACITY']
    """

    random.seed(0)

    # Random data will be in these bounds.
    valid_interfaces = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F')
    valid_classes = ('FIRM', 'NON-FIRM', 'SECONDARY')
    min_date = datetime(2022, 1, 1)
    max_date = datetime(2023, 1, 1)

    # Random date genertor
    def rand_date(min_date, max_date):
        days = (max_date - min_date).days
        return min_date + timedelta(days=random.randrange(days))

    records = records or 100
    interfaces = random.choices(valid_interfaces, k=records)
    classes = random.choices(valid_classes, k=records)
    starts = [rand_date(min_date, max_date) for _ in range(records)]
    stops = [rand_date(_, max_date) for _ in starts]
    capacities = [random.randint(-10000, 10000) for _ in range(records)]

    data = {'INTERFACE': interfaces,
            'CLASS': classes,
            'START_TIME': starts,
            'STOP_TIME': stops,
            'CAPACITY': capacities
            }
    return pd.DataFrame(data)


def calc_hourly_totals(data: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """
    Create a dataframe with net capacity by hour, interface and class.
    :param data: pd.DataFrame with columns ['INTERFACE', 'CLASS', 'START_TIME',
                                            'STOP_TIME', 'CAPACITY']
    :return: pd.DataFrame with columns ['INTERFACE', 'CLASS', 'HOUR_BEGINNING',
                                        'CAPACITY']
    """
    min_date = data.START_TIME.min()
    max_date = data.START_TIME.max()

    hourly_dates = [min_date + timedelta(hours=_) for _
                    in range((max_date - min_date).days * 24
                             + int((max_date - min_date).seconds / 3600)
                             )
                    ]
    # print('hourly_dates:', hourly_dates)
    result = pd.DataFrame(columns=['INTERFACE', 'CLASS',
                                   'HOUR_BEGINNING', 'CAPACITY'])
    loop = 0
    for hour_start in hourly_dates:
        hour_stop = hour_start + timedelta(hours=1)
        # Filter data. Keep only the ones that overlap within this day/hour.
        df = data[(data.START_TIME < np.datetime64(hour_stop))
                  & (data.STOP_TIME > np.datetime64(hour_start))]
        df = df.groupby(['INTERFACE', 'CLASS']).sum('CAPACITY')
        df['HOUR_BEGINNING'] = hour_start
        df.reset_index(inplace=True)  # Move INTERFACE from index to a column.
        df = df[['INTERFACE', 'CLASS', 'HOUR_BEGINNING', 'CAPACITY']]

        result = pd.concat([result, df])
        # loop += 1
        # if loop % 1000 == 0:
        #     print(f'   completed {loop} of {len(hourly_dates)} loops.')

    result.rename(columns={'CAPACITY': 'NET_CAPACITY'}, inplace=True)
    result.reset_index(inplace=True)
    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from time import perf_counter

    test_data = make_test_data(1_000)
    # test_data = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Personal\projects\tsd_python\data\net_tsr_data_2021_04_01-2022_04_01.xlsx',
    #                           sheet_name='Raw TSR Data')
    print('test data rows:', len(test_data))
    t_start = perf_counter()
    result = calc_hourly_totals(test_data)
    t_finish = perf_counter()
    print('computation time:', t_finish - t_start)
    print(result.head())
```

My results look like this:

```
test data rows: 1000
computation time: 38.52079169999888
   index INTERFACE      CLASS      HOUR_BEGINNING NET_CAPACITY
0      0         A       FIRM 2022-01-01 00:00:00        -8646
1      1         B  SECONDARY 2022-01-01 00:00:00        -2296
2      2         E  SECONDARY 2022-01-01 00:00:00         7927
3      0         A       FIRM 2022-01-01 01:00:00        -8646
4      1         B  SECONDARY 2022-01-01 01:00:00        -2296

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to trade off speed for memory and you have enough of the latter, the following could work:

```
# Calculate all possible time-points - similar to hourly_dates but with an additional time-point at the end 
hour_beginning = pd.Series(pd.date_range(test_data['START_TIME'].min(), test_data['STOP_TIME'].max(), freq='H'))

# Remove this additional -last- time-point
hour_beginning = hour_beginning.drop(hour_beginning.index[-1])
```

You then calculate the cartesian product of the possible `INTERFACE`, `CLASS` and `hour_beginning` values:

```
interfaces = test_data['INTERFACE'].unique()
classes = test_data['CLASS'].unique()

# Import itertools
comb = pd.DataFrame(
    itertools.product(interfaces, classes, hour_beginning),
    columns=['INTERFACE', 'CLASS', 'HOUR_BEGINNING'],
)
```

Then you merge the `test_data` with the product `df`, but select only the time-points between `START_TIME` and `END_TIME`:

```
df_mrg = test_data.merge(comb, on = ['INTERFACE', 'CLASS']).query('START_TIME <= HOUR_BEGINNING < STOP_TIME')
```

Finally you `groupby` and `sum`:

```
result2 = df_mrg.groupby(['INTERFACE', 'CLASS', 'HOUR_BEGINNING']).sum(numeric_only=True)
result2 = result2.reset_index().sort_values(['INTERFACE', 'CLASS', 'HOUR_BEGINNING']).rename(columns={'CAPACITY': 'NET_CAPACITY'})
```

`result2` is equal to "your" `result` sorted:

```
result1 = result.drop('index', axis = 1).sort_values(['INTERFACE', 'CLASS', 'HOUR_BEGINNING'])
result1.reset_index(drop=True).compare(result2.reset_index(drop=True)) # Raises no error
```

On Colab the new aggregation takes 1.7 sec, the old 1 min 27 sec.

Comment: Thank you for this solution and the detailed walkthrough.

Comment: Did it run fast for the real (larger) dataset?

Comment: I got an np core exception.  I have about 12 of 16 GB of memory free.  I ran 25,000 rows successfully in about 82 seconds.  When I tried 35,000 rows, I got an exception. numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError: Unable to allocate 6.83 GiB for an array with shape (3, 305760000) and data type datetime64[ns]

Comment: My "real" data comes in chunks of whole hours (up to 24 hours, not contained in a day), calendar day, calendar week, calendar month, or years.  The "years" data can start on any day (midnight) and end on any day (midnight) that is at least one year more than the start date.  IAn "hourly" record can start on any hour of the day and end up to 24 hours later, thus, it can cross months.  About 90% of my records are hourly data.  If I create 12 sets of monthly data, I don't expect to have many more records in total.  Or perhaps I'll sort the data, then create 25,000 row chunks.

Comment: In which step? When creating comb or when you merge the two datasets?

Comment: I was thinking of dividing test_data into subsets like [data1, data2, ...].  However, comb is still very large.  On further thought, maybe I should divide comb into multiple smaller dataframes.

Comment: I broke up comb to 10,000 row chunks and looped through.  On my laptop, it took just under 10 minutes.

Comment: You just have to make sure there is no overlap between the chunks, I guess that's the case in your solution. Thanks for the update.